# Attachments in CSR list form

Tags: client-side-rendering

I have customized my page using CSR list form . How to display attachment in the edit and display form?

Comment: You're going to have to provide much more detail if you want help with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mostly get all my stuff with REST. Also the Attachment URL.

Check my blogpost here: https://blog.afrait.com/get-attachment-url-from-list-item/

Or take a look at the script below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        // Rest URL
        var requestUri = "/_api/lists/getbytitle('Marketplace')/items?$select=Title,ID,Attachments,AttachmentFiles&$expand=AttachmentFiles";

            $.ajax({
                url: requestUri,
                type: "GET",
                headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
                success: function (data) {

                    $.each(data.d.results, function (i, item){
                        var title = item.Title;
                        var id = item.ID;
                        var attachmentUrl = item.AttachmentFiles.results[0];

                        //alert(attachmentUrl.FileName);
                        //alert(attachmentUrl.ServerRelativeUrl);

                    })
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Error getting the Marketplace Items");
                }                     
            });
      });      

</script>
```

Comment: HI Patrik , Thanks for ur help . I have used similar kind of code and got the output . Do u know how to attach the file in edit and display form . I have customized my page using CSR list form